# How to set varnish backend connection idle timeout?

Tags: varnish, vcl

We have varnish-6.4.0 servers with AWS NLB as backend. As you know NLB has fixed idle timeout 350sec and silently closes the connection. So, would like to control the idle connections at Varnish.
Is there a way to close idle connection by varnish after 110sec?

Varnish --> AWS NLB --> nodejs

Also, is there a way to test this behavior?

Thank,
Sar

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `backend_idle_timeout` runtime parameter and set it to a desired value. The default value is 60 seconds.

See http://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/varnishd.html#backend-idle-timeout for more information.

Comment: Hello Feryn, Thanks for your response. I  tried using backend_idle_timeout parameter. But, how to test the connection status? Could you please help?

Comment: Just run `varnishlog -g request` to see all information regarding a transaction. This includes backend connection information.